# openCV display image grey if getchar

Tags: windows, opencv

In order to not let displayed image flash off, I put a getchar(). It was windows console project.

```
cv::Mat image= cv::imread("me.jpg");
cv::namedWindow("Image1");
cv::imshow("Image1",image);
getchar();
```

The "Image1" windows is grey and seems to be "no response"
while if I change the `getchar()` into `cv:waitKey(5000)`, it behaves normally.
Why, does it have anything to do with process?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imshow() just copies an image ref, waitKey() does the (window)message pumping, without it, your program won't ever get to the point, where the actual blitting happens

Comment: and I guess there are other ways to pump images?

Comment: well, it's not about pumping images, but messages. gui programs (believe it or not, this is one!) have a different program flow, than console ones. the code in waitKey() is what would happen in the main loop normally, so if you don't call it, that code to draw the imge will never get executed. additionally, if you call getchar(), it will block the whole program ( also, it would wait for a key from the konsole window, not the gui one )